# What is the use of if(arr[i] != -1) in this c program?

Tags: c

What is the use of  `if(arr[i] != -1`) in this c program. This is the program to count the frequency of repeated elements in the array. Looking for the answer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int arr[100], freq[100], i, j, size, count = 0;
  printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", & size);
  printf("Enter the elements of the array\n");
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) //loop to store the elements in the array
  {
    scanf("%d", & arr[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    count = 1;
    if (arr[i] != -1) `Here what is the use of if(arr[i] != -1`
    {

      for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) //increment j by 1 value of i to comapre it
      {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) // comapring i elements with j
        {
          count++;
          arr[j] = -1;
        }
      }
      freq[i] = count; // storing how many times a number count in the array freq[i]
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) // loop to print the result
  {
    if (arr[i] != -1) {
      printf("%d repeated %d times in the array.\n", arr[i], freq[i]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use a C comment so you don't produce a compile error: if (arr[i] != -1) `Here what is the use of if(arr[i] != -1`

Comment: Add some code that prints the content if the `arr` array at the end of `main` . Then you'll understand on your own.

Comment: @wildplasser I think it's more commonly referred to as a sentinel value.

Comment: Just as a side note: It is not safe to use `scanf()` without checking the return value. See this page for more information: [A beginner's guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: @FiddlingBits: IMHO `sentinel` is used if the value is used to indicate the *end* of a sequence, such as `\0' in C-strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming -1 is never entered as part of "Enter the elements of the array"**...

> What is the use of `if(arr[i] != -1)` ?

For this application, when an element is -1, it effective says: no longer examine the array element.

---

Below code is walking the array, visiting each of the first `size` elements.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  count = 1;
  if (arr[i] != -1)
  ...
```

Within the loop is the below which `count++;` to indicate a repeat was found and then assigns `arr[j] = -1;` to **mark the element** as already accounted for in the repeat search and to not use that element anymore.

```
    if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
      count++;
      arr[j] = -1;
    }
```

Then only when `if (arr[i] != -1)` is true, will a repeat get search for or printed.

Answer (score 0):

arr is an array, and loop is running for i, so i is just number depend on loop like 1,2,3 and so on.
when we write arr[i], it means we are referring to ith index of arr. For example if we write arr[1], it means we referring to element in arr at index 1. 
So, when we are checking

> arr[i] != -1

it means we are checking that if element at ith position of arr is not equal to -1.

```
if (arr[i] != -1) //Here if element is not -1 only then control will go in this block
    {

      for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) //increment j by 1 value of i to comapre it
      {
        if (arr[i] == arr[j]) // comapring i elements with j
        {
          count++;
          arr[j] = -1;
        }
      }
      freq[i] = count; // storing how many times a number count in the array freq[i]
    }
```